# Print the function name of all functions travelled until current one

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, qt5, qmake

In the Qt world we can print current function name with [Q_FUNC_INFO](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_FUNC_INFO).

Considering the case where user press a button and eventually `myfunction` gets called, and there are multiple function calls in between (i.e. `func1`, `func2`, ...).

I would like to see the history of all functions called until it reaches `myfunction`:

```
func1
func2
myfunction
```

One way to accomplish that is to carefully debug it and add a `qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;` to each function, I'll call this a manual approach. And I was wondering if there is a smarter approach, so that I can mark just start and end points and it will print the travelled functions?

Comment: C++23 adds `<stacktrace>`, but you’ve excluded that via tags.

Comment: If `boost` is an option you might want to look at [`boost.stacktrace`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html).

Comment: @DavisHerring C++23? Are you coming from the future? Is there an implementation of that on the compilers of these  days?

Comment: @G.M. I never played with boost. And the project I'm looking now is based on Qt, is `boost.stacktrace` expected to work in the Qt land?

Comment: Boost stacktrace didn't work for me. It's bugged. I recommend the excellent backward-cpp. I patched it to also print the javascript-backtrace of QML in the same format (my patch is closed source, so I can't provide it!). Hacking it is simple.

Comment: @KcFnMi: The C++ committee plans language versions every three years, and the usual suspects already [document it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/basic_stacktrace).  The standard libraries [don’t have it yet](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23), but Boost in particular is often the precursor for the standardized interface.